# Azure devops not running xunit tests

Tags: azure-devops

In test run log I have `Run UnitTests` step, which uses `Visual Studio Test`. However I see log message:

`No test is available in C:\stuff\Debug\x64\bin\x86\ilc\MyApp.Test.dll some_other_dlls  Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.`

Test are visible in visual studio, and I can run all of them (I have over 50 tests).
I have xunit.runner.visualstudio package installed. What I am missing, why Azure ignores my tests?

```
**************** Starting test execution *********************
\vstest.console.exe "@C:\path\fadisfjla.tmp"
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 16.4.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
vstest.console.exe "C:\dir\Release\x64\bin\arm\MyApp.Test\testhost.dll"
"C:\dir\Release\x64\bin\arm\MyApp.Test\xunit.runner.visualstudio.uwp.testadapter.dll"
"C:\dir\Release\x64\bin\arm\ilc\MyApp.Test.dll"
"C:\dir\Release\x64\bin\x86\MyApp.Test\testhost.dll"
"C:\dir\Release\x64\bin\x86\MyApp.Test\xunit.runner.visualstudio.uwp.testadapter.dll"
"C:\dir\Release\x64\bin\x86\ilc\MyApp.Test.dll"
/Settings:"C:\tmp\fadslfj.tmp.runsettings"

/EnableCodeCoverage
/Logger:"trx"
/TestAdapterPath:"C:\dir\Release\x64"
Starting test execution, please wait...
Test run will use DLL(s) built for framework .NETFramework,Version=v4.0 and platform X86. Following DLL(s) do not match framework/platform settings.
testhost.dll is built for Framework .NETStandard,Version=v1.4 and Platform AnyCPU.
xunit.runner.visualstudio.uwp.testadapter.dll is built for Framework .NETCore,Version=v5.0 and Platform AnyCPU.
MyApp.Test.dll is built for Framework .NETFramework,Version=v4.0 and Platform ARM.
testhost.dll is built for Framework .NETStandard,Version=v1.4 and Platform AnyCPU.
xunit.runner.visualstudio.uwp.testadapter.dll is built for Framework .NETCore,Version=v5.0 and Platform AnyCPU.
Go to more details on managing these settings.
Microsoft (R) Coverage Collection Tool Version 16.0.30319.200


Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.




1.5873
A total of 6 test files matched the specified pattern.
No test is available in C:\dir\Release\x64\bin\arm\MyApp.Test\testhost.dll C:\dir\Release\x64\bin\arm\MyApp.Test\xunit.runner.visualstudio.uwp.testadapter.dll C:\dir\Release\x64\bin\arm\ilc\MyApp.Test.dll C:\dir\Release\x64\bin\x86\MyApp.Test\testhost.dll C:\dir\Release\x64\bin\x86\MyApp.Test\xunit.runner.visualstudio.uwp.testadapter.dll C:\dir\Release\x64\bin\x86\ilc\MyApp.Test.dll. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.
Microsoft (R) Coverage Collection Tool Version 16.0.30319.200


Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.




Results File: C:\path\fdsfdsfd.trx
Attachments:
  C:\path\file-dfsfdsfe.coverage
Vstest.console.exe exited with code 0.
```

In my project file

```
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio">
      <Version>2.4.1</Version>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
```

Comment: How did you set `Visual Studio Test` task? Could you share the detailed log?

Comment: I have included log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that if You have UWP project for Windows version `1803`, and refrence it from test project in this version it ignores all tests in test project. I think this is issue in xunit or windows sdk. If just test project is updated to `1903` it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have added the `xunit.runner.visualstudio` package. And then make sure you have pointed to your generated test assemblies under `Test selection/Test files`in `Visual Studio Test` task, for example:

```
**\bin\$(BuildConfiguration)\**\*test*.dll
!**\obj\**
!**\xunit.runner.visualstudio.testadapter.dll
!**\xunit.runner.visualstudio.dotnetcore.testadapter.dll
```

Check the following link:

https://xunit.net/docs/getting-test-results-in-azure-devops

Comment: In the log I can see that "6 assemblies" matched specification, and no tests were found inside. Also I can see that xunit.runner.visualstudio is installed in test project.

Comment: Do you add the `xunit.runner.visualstudio` in packages.config file in your project? It seems you shared local log, could you share the log in your DevOps build?

Comment: My project does not have packages.config file, I am using `<PackageReference>` in project files. Log file is from azure, but I have changed all paths and other sensitive information.

Comment: You may try to use NuGet Package Manager to add `xunit.runner.visualstudio` to your project and create a new build pipeline to see how's the result.

Comment: How's your issue going? Have you tried using NuGet Package Manager to add `xunit.runner.visualstudio` package to your project and create a new build pipeline?

Comment: Apparently it was bug in windows SDK, maybe related to xunit runner.